# How to mock the external API's service calls using mockwebserver ? I am calling my controller through web test client

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp, spring-webflux

We are calling controller through web test client. I have 2 external api calls in my service class. Now i want to write the test cases for these scenarios.
Please suggest me how to mock those external service calls using mock web server.

I tried like below but its calling actual external calls.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class })
public class FunctionalTest {
@Autowired
public MockWebServer mockWebServer;
@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
@Before
public void setUp() {
this.webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(this.context).configureClient() //
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:2020")
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs((configurer) -> {
                configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper));
                configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper));
            }).build()).build();

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

 @Test
public void testMyInfo() throws Exception {
    MockResponse businessResponse = new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).setBody(getRequestDataFromFile("business.json"));

    MockResponse cheapResponse = new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).setBody(getRequestDataFromFile("cheap.json"));

   mockWebServer.setDispatcher(new Dispatcher() {
        @Override
        public MockResponse dispatch(RecordedRequest request) {
            if (request.getPath().endsWith("/business"))
                return businessResponse;
            if (request.getPath().endsWith("/cheap")) {
                return cheapResponse;
            }
            return cheapResponse;

        }
      });
     testResponse(webTestClient);
  }

public void testResponse(final WebTestClient webTestClient) {
    ((WebTestClient.RequestBodySpec) 
   webTestClient.get().uri("/webflux")).exchange().expectStatus().isEqualTo(200)
            .expectBody(Data[].class).consumeWith(result -> {

                System.out.println("result........." + result);

            });
}
```

Comment: Created MockWebServer and WebClient  beans like this                    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
 public MockWebServer mockWebServer() {
  return new MockWebServer();
 }

 @Primary
 @Bean("webClient")
 public WebClient webClient(MockWebServer mockWebServer) {

  return WebClient.create("https://srihsri.com/api1/flights");
 }

Comment: Here I am expecting mock response which i am setting into the mockWebServer.setDispatcher(-) but its calling actual external API call